# How to get data from UP501 gps module on Arduino?

Tags: gps, arduino

I am trying to use UP501 gps module on Arduino and get a raw information from the GPS like long, lat,alt..etc

I am running this code on Arduino to see if the serial on GPS is available, if it is then print out the data from GPS.

**Arduino Code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX .

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(57600); 
  Serial.println("Searching using GPS...");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

**My problem: I don't get any data from the GPS module.**

I thought it would be from the wiring. See the picture below of my wiring.

- yellow wire from pin 2 is connected to D10 which will be the RX
- black wire from pin 3 is connected to ground.
- Red wire from pin 4 is connected to 3.3 volts

Note: I went outside(outdoor) to get a satellite but no information

[image: wiring]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tutorial](http://www.adafruit.com/products/660#Tutorials) on adafruit for using this gps

I sugest you take a look at it becuse your wireing seems to be missing a few things